# Install Windows XP Home by loading it on the hdd

Tags: windows-xp, installation

I have an old laptop without USB or network boot and with broken CD reader (but working floppy unit).
The only method that seems to be good for me to install a fresh XP is to extract the HDD, put installation files on a dedicated partition and boot from it.

I can understand the main line of this method but I need detailed instructions on how to correctly make the partition bootable etc.

I read about similar problems around, but no-one detailed the process.
e.g. [Install WinXP without CD/pendrive](https://superuser.com/questions/267848/install-winxp-without-cd-pendrive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can take out the hard drive, why not buy a cheap second hand optical drive < £10 and use that?

Otherwise, yes it is possible to do what you want.

Extract the hard drive, and partition a NTFS partition that takes up the entire drive, apart from about 1GB.

Format this 1GB partition as FAT32.

from your Windows XP disk, copy the I386 folder to the Fat32 partition.

Next, you will need a Windows 98 or XP floppy disk - I hope you have one around, if not you can download an image from many places (A good one is http://www.bootdisk.com/ ).

Once booted from the floppy, type the following:

```
c:
cd\i386
winnt
```

And, it has been about 10 years since I have done this... I think you have to create three boot floppys from here (I think there is a switch to skip this, but I can't remember).

Anyway, this should allow you to install Windows XP without problems!

Comment: "I think you have to create three boot floppys from here (I think there is a switch to skip this, but I can't remember)."   I've never heard of 3 boot floppies at all, maybe you're thinking of a boot floppy with 3 files on it NTLDR,boot.ini,ntdetect.com And that win xp 3 file boot disk is not related to this though.

Comment: Also you haven't answered how he should partition it. What program he should use/run to do it.

Comment: Ok, apart form the boot floppys (are they a security measure or needed?) it will be the same setup as the cd one, right?

Comment: @FiloSottile There are no boot floppies. Yes it's the same setup as the CD.

Comment: @FiloSottile Actually, you could use one boot floppy, (not plural).

Comment: No problem on small how-to's like partitioning, I'm a 5-years adv linux user and, you know... ;)

Comment: It's not an XP Boot disk. It's a Windows 9X(95/98/ME) boot disk.

Comment: I think I will be fine. Thanks. 
@barlop is there a way to give credit also to you?

Comment: @FiloSottile Yes to the left of comments if you move the mouse there, an up arrow appears allowing you to upvote the comment

Comment: @Barlop - I figured anyone wanting to remove the hard drive to do this would know how to partition (and I was right)... As for the floppy drive, this is needed unless you also want to make the fat32 partition bootable... and from what I remember there was a stage where you create an additional 3 floppies, I just don't remember the exact details.

Comment: @barlop I'll be back when i will have enough reputation, i can't still upvote there

Comment: @FiloSottile You have to make the i386 directory on a FAT32 partition because a Win9X boot disk cannot (naturally/natively) read NTFS, but can read FAT12(FDD)/16/32. Leave lots of space for an NTFS partition, the windows setup can create the NTFS partition.

Comment: @Wil  I've done it never had to use 3 floppies. Only one bootable, to boot win9x from.  I'd have to use my imagination for how any others could be necessary or wanted e.g. could use another(not bootable) if you have a SATA Hard Drive on RAID controller and it needs  a driver on a floppy during win xp installation. Or if you want an unnecessary amount of commands on the floppy you could have more on a second non bootable one.

Comment: had a look, it is Windows 2000 that requires 3 boot floppies... Windows XP has it just as an optional stage

Comment: @FiloSottile +1 on the question so you are a little closer to voting.

Comment: @Wil do you have a link about Win2k and 3 floppies? or win xp's optional stage?

Comment: @Wil I've read of Win2k having a 4 floppy thing (I wouldn't call them boot floppies). And i've used a set of 6 for Win XP, to get to the recovery console, maybe win2k's 4 are for that, but are you sure about win2k and three?